# Fit a non-linear model in R with restrictions

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to fit a model to some data in R. To simplify the question, I'll use an example.

If the model that describes my process is `y = f(a, b)` where `a` cannot be greater than `b`. Is there a way I can fit the model with this restriction?

I'm using `nlsLM` but am open to other methods/packages if necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package nlsLM and many other software libraries that perform non-linear regression have the possibility to use upper and lower limits for the parameters to be estimated.

When you rewrite your function as $$f(a,a+c)$$ by substituting $b=a+c$, then the restriction $a\leq b$ becomes $c \geq 0$ and the latter restriction you can regulate with upper/lower boundaries.

---

Other ways are

- (re-)write your own optimisation algorithm.

  I imagine this could in some cases improve performance, ie increase convergence rate.
- Substitute $f(a,a+e^c)$ such that the non-negative limit is obtained without specifying a boundary, but by using a function that is non-negative.

How to do approach this exactly will depend on your actual problem. There should be several examples here already. (To be honest they might not be easy to find, or at least I tried a few search prompts and they did not reveal them. Yet, I believe that I have seen these type of questions before)

Comment: your second "Other way" seems like the play for anyone not comfortable with optimization, since many nonlinear least squares solvers in R don't allow even box constraints.

Comment: Method 1 worked perfectly. I specified `lower` with `nlsLM` to prevent the difference between `a` and `b` being less than 0.